# Recover gedit file after save and restart

Tags: files, data-recovery, gedit, restart

Is it possible to recover the old data of a file after it was erased by another file and restart ?

Comment: So you overwrote the content of a file in GEdit? Did you have backup-on-save enabled in GEdit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends how you edited / deleted and how many times the content. Some editors like `gedit` creates a backup copy of file before saving with the '~' (tilde) suffix. These files  with the '~' suffix are hidden files for most of file managers (like Nautilus). So, with a little bit of luck you can recovery your lost content from these files.

**Note** - In case if you are not using gedit than for backup on vi editor have a look at [this article.](http://www.gmarks.org/vi_backups.html)

Hope it helps